# MKLocalSearch.start returning undocumented MKErrorGEOError

Tags: ios, mapkit

[MKLocalSearch.start](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalsearch/1452652-start) is giving me `MKErrorGEOError=-8` which is not documented in [MKError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkerror).

- **This only happens in my CI machine!**
- This only happens when running the tests, the app code works fine
- I tried enabling location services on macOS just in case, but it didn't work.
- That machine shouldn't have any network requests/URLs blocked

What fixed for me was to add `request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Venue"`, but I don't understand why, nor why this would fix an error that is happening in only 1 machine.

Does anyone have any information about this?

---

Here's some sample code:

```
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Venue" // this fixes it, but why?!
let ibereCamargoMuseumCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -30.0777596,
                                                           longitude: -51.2477212)
let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 5, longitudeDelta: 5)
request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: ibereCamargoMuseumCoordinates, span: span)
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    request.resultTypes = .pointOfInterest
}

let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
localSearch.start { response, error in
    ...
}
```

Here's some debugging output:

```
(lldb) po error
Error Domain=MKErrorDomain Code=4 "(null)" UserInfo={MKErrorGEOError=-8}

(lldb) po error.userInfo
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("MKErrorGEOError")
      - value : "MKErrorGEOError"
    - value : -8
```

---

If you're interested I asked this on [Apple dev forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677654) too

Comment: I'm curious what sense it makes to do a natural language query without a `.naturalLanguageQuery` string.

Comment: One possible use case I can see is listing all `.pointOfInterest` in a region span.

Comment: `MKLocalSearch` is not made to give you all points of interest in e region. It is made to o let the user search for a natural string like `Pizza`. Even then, the number of results are limited to 10.